# Possible to mark system classes or methods as obsolete in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Is it possible to apply [Obsolete attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664623%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to system classes or methods? If so, how? If not, can I instruct Visual Studio to warn on certain code patterns?

Specifically, I'd like to mark the use of Session/Session["key"] as obsolete in favor of a possible singleton.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to mark types defined in other assemblies as obselete.  The `ObsoleteAttribute` can only be applied to types in source code that you are compiling.

There is no existing Visual Studio tool I'm aware of which provides this capability.  If you are interested in persueing it though, the best option is likely to write an FxCop rule which targets this type.

Comment: That certainly answers the question. Thanks!