# Throw an error at compile time if a particular external function is used anywhere in the code?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm using an external library and I want to make sure I never call some particular functions in the library. I don't have the source code for that library so I'd like to make sure that at compile time it throws an error if I ever accidentally (or one of my developers) ever use that function. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Remove those functions from the header?

Comment: @AlexD What headers? C# doesn't have headers, just metadata...

Comment: Ha, and that makes three of us that totally missed the `#` in `C#`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Possible to mark system classes or methods as obsolete in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413761/possible-to-mark-system-classes-or-methods-as-obsolete-in-c)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Hard to say if its a duplicate, it says that one normal way to do this (marking methods obsolete) isn't going to work, but doesn't preclude a different approach.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET If no one else agrees, then the link serves as a good cross-reference.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Don't think it's a duplicate, OP is asking to throw an error.

Comment: @LIUFA ...which is exactly what happens at compile-time, when you try to call a function marked `[Obsolete("...", true)]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this *easily*. You could mark the method as obsolete, but of course that requires access to the external library source code, at which point you could also just remove the methods.

The next best thing I can come up with is to build a facade around the library object:

```
public class LibraryFacade
{
    //All the library methods as pass-through methods
    //Except the bad ones!
}
```

Of course, your developers have to actually *use* the facade for this to help. If you don't trust them at all, you could get new developers, or put the facade in a separate assembly so the client code doesn't have direct access to the external library.

Obviously thats a lot of work for this kind of feature, but it will get you where you are trying to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you have plenty of extra time you can make a clone of the external assembly and link against your slimmed down version with identical method signatures instead of real one and replace with real assembly at run-time/post compile. Easy for non-signed assemblies, I think you can even do that if other assembly is signed by using delay-sign feature.

Benefits: complete intellisence/refactoring support, perfect build errors.

Drawbacks: picking right subset of methods may be major pain if library uses a lot of dependencies, getting 100% parity may be hard.